# How to get the id of a user via REST?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I'm using SharePoint 2013 on premises and I want to get the Id of a user to later change the Author of a listitem. I've used this url "`/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='{1}`", but the id I get for my user is 15 and I know that my user id is 9, What am I doing bad?

Comment: do you want to get user by it's login name?

Comment: I only want the Id of the user by it's login name, then with that Id I would change the author id of an item list

Answer (score 6):

There is one more way to get ID of current logged user using "_spPageContextInfo" object.

Please refer following code -->

```
_spPageContextInfo.userId
```

Reference - [Understanding the _spPageContextInfo object](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29766.sharepoint-understanding-the-sppagecontextinfo-object.aspx)

Comment: This will not work outside of a SharePoint page

Comment: Yes Jigar, you are right, this object is available only on SharePoint pages.

Comment: Yes, that is not what I need, anyway thanks Rohit.